# Use jQuery to Detect Container Overflow?

Tags: jquery, css, overflow

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059743/detect-elements-overflow-using-jquery) but feel like there has to be a "cleaner" jQuery method of doing this. I'm not even sure if this really works in all scenarios. Is there a way for jQuery to determine if a container has overflow without comparing dimensions?

For clarification, is there a method to test whether the CSS attribute `overflow: hidden` has kicked in and is hiding content?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [detect elements overflow using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059743/detect-elements-overflow-using-jquery)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$.fn.hasOverflow = function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $children = $this.find('*');
    var len = $children.length;

    if (len) {
        var maxWidth = 0;
        var maxHeight = 0
        $children.map(function(){
            maxWidth = Math.max(maxWidth, $(this).outerWidth(true));
            maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight, $(this).outerHeight(true));
        });

        return maxWidth > $this.width() || maxHeight > $this.height();
    }

    return false;
};
```

Example:

```
var $content = $('#content').children().wrapAll('<div>');
while($content.hasOverflow()){
    var size = parseFloat($content.css('font-size'), 10);
    size -= 1;
    $content.css('font-size', size + 'px');
}
```

Comment: This assumes that children are not inlined, in which case we might have to check the sum of all widths/heights.

Answer (score 5):

You may change the css attributes to fit your needs.

```
$.fn.hasOverflow = function() {
    $(this).css({ overflow: "auto", display: "table" });
    var h1 = $(this).outerHeight();

    $(this).css({ overflow: "hidden", display: "block" });
    var h2 = $(this).outerHeight();

    return (h1 > h2) ? true : false;
};
```

Comment: `return (h1 > h2) ? true : false;` is repetitive… `return h1 > h2;` should be enough ;)

Answer (score 1):

There is no clean method. You could make it two wrappers, the outer wrapper having `overflow: hidden`, and comparing the two wrappers' dimensions, but anything you could possibly do would end up being hacky. If the functionality really is necessary, then you'll have to live with the hacks.

Comment: sigh... i suppose you're right. thanks for your help. i implemented a fairly painless `width` check. i'll let this run a bit to see if anyone has an actual solution before i accept.

Comment: Just came across this, looking to make a menu on a page which never has a scroll bar (i.e. the body is "fixed" to 100% width / height so that I can stick the footer to the bottom without overlapping the content). I would like to detect if the menu overflows and, if so, display a button to move down (rather than an 'orrible scroll bar, so it slides down smoothly using jQuery). Guess I'll just have to live with the hacks too, unless the other answer can do what I need. Anyway the reason I started commenting was simply to say @Jason that I think this has run for a lot **more** than a while!!

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution I have found is to detect the `scrollWidth` of the `parent()`:

```
var totalWidth = $(this).parent()[0].scrollWidth;
```

---

...I think the `0` index is referring to the "root node" of the parent, obtaining the property from there.

Answer (score 0):

There exists another solution, (this example tests if the height overflows) it requires the overflowing container to be `position:relative`:

### HTML

```
<div id="overflowing-container" style="position:relative">
    <div class="children"></div>
    <div class="children"></div>
    <div class="children"></div>
</div>
```

### Javascript

```
     var last = $('.children:last'), container=$('#overflowing-container')
         lastOffsetHeight = container.scrollTop() + last.outerHeight(true) + last.position().top;

     if (last[0] && lastOffsetHeight > container[0].getBoundingClientRect().height) {
       console.log("thisContainerOverflows")     
     }
```