# Can I detect an overflow event in jquery?

Tags: jquery, events, overflow

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112106/use-jquery-to-detect-container-overflow), but I am wondering if there is any way to detect an overflow *event*.

I have a div that gets resized by some jquery code, but then at some point later the content of that div changes and the css height:auto rule is no longer effective because a previous event set the height, so the display messes up.

I want to be able to catch the overflow event so I can reset the height of the div to auto. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is helpful at all, but I thought it was worth a shot:

FF: http://help.dottoro.com/ljgsfkbc.php

Chrom & Safari: http://help.dottoro.com/ljbnnejo.php