# Limit input symbols by square of textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frontend

Is there a way to limit count of symbols by square of textarea.
For example when I enter some text in the textarea it should stop after the text reaches the end of its visible area(right bottom corner).

*More details*:
I want the input stops like on the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: `textarea { overflow : hidden }`? You could also use `textarea { text-overflow : ellipsis }`.

Comment: do you realize your count will be different depending on os, browser, user settings ?

Comment: @mikakun I realize that it is unusual task, nevertheless I think it might be some solutions. Maybe it can be unique browsers function.

Comment: @JaceCotton Thanks, but your suggestion doesn't suit this situation. I need to prevent any input from user after text reaches the end of textarea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow - I had no idea that `<textarea>` supported an `onoverflow` and `onoverflowchanged` events:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events

Plug in a JavaScript callback that annoys the user when they write one too many characters, and make the field about to overflow. And good luck characterizing the browser support for such a rare event...

Comment: Thank you, also I have found another useful post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10431659/can-i-detect-an-overflow-event-in-jquery