# HTML - JS - Is there a way to trigger an event when inline "display" property of a div changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have HTML like this

```
<!-- some other HTML -->
    <div class="GlobalHeaderScope stop-scroll" id="HFNotificationsPane" style="height: 1016px; overflow: visible; display: block; opacity: 1;">
<!-- some more HTML -->
    </div>    
<!-- some more HTML -->
```

Is there some way to trigger an event (custom or built-in) when the inline css `overflow: visible;` changes to `overflow: hidden;`

I have looked around, but couldn't find a way to do it. Sorry if my question is ambiguous.

Comment: How you are changing the css?Using jquery or javascript? If jquery which function you are using?

Comment: That would all depend when and where/how the `css` is changed for you know know when/how to trigger a *"custom or built-in"* function.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10431659/can-i-detect-an-overflow-event-in-jquery