# Can someone explain this return statement for me?

Tags: javascript

I have a return statement that was used in [this Stackover answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4219164/1261316), that I can't quite understand. Here it is:

```
return maxWidth > $this.width() || maxHeight > $this.height();
```

What does it mean to return something in way?

*I'll edit the title of this question after an answer as soon as I know what it is :)*

Comment: Are you unclear about the `||` operator, or something else?

Comment: It's a logical operator. `||` is "Or" so if the left side is true or the right side is true, return true. If neither are true it returns false.

Comment: I understand `||`, but it's just the whole combination in that one return statement that perplexes me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the equivalent of:

```
if (maxWidth > $this.width() || maxHeight > $this.height()) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

In other words, if either `maxWidth` is greater than the `width()` of `$this` **or** `maxHeight` is greater than the `height()` of `$this`, it will return `true`; otherwise, it will return `false`.

Comment: Does this way of returning a value have a special name?

Comment: @Owen: Not really, it's just less verbose, and a common idiom for functions that return a `boolean` value. For example, if you have a function that takes an integer, and returns `true` if the integer is greater than 5, and `false` otherwise, you can just write `return i > 5`, which is less verbose than `if (i > 5) { return true } else { return false }`.

Answer (score 3):

It returns `boolean`.

```
return maxWidth > $this.width() || maxHeight > $this.height();
```

Assume,

```
maxWidth = 300 
$this.width() = 200
maxHeight = 400
$this.height() = 500
```

so it returns

```
(300>200 || 400>500) ==> (T || F) ==> TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

In that particular example the code is checking if the biggest child dimension exceeds the parent dimension, the dimensions being width and height.

Answer (score 1):

It's known as [short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND_%28.26.26%29), and in this case will return a boolean value. If

```
maxWidth > $this.width()
```

is true, it'll return `true`, without evaluating the second test. Otherwise it'll return the result of evaluating

```
maxHeight > $this.height().
```

Answer (score 0):

It returns true if one of the dimension of `$this`, which is a jQuery wrapper object created as `$(this)`, is smaller than some variables.

In the code you link too, that enables the detection of overflowing as `maxWidth` and `minWidth` are the dimensions of the biggest child : if one child is bigger than this, then it is overflowing this.

Have a look at the [width](http://api.jquery.com/width/) function.

Answer (score 0):

its a bool value, so if the maximum of width or height is greater than real width, then you get true.