# how to find text overflow in a circle div using jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

How to find or detect if the text inside the div is overflowing by this i can reduce the font-size so that the text content will fit in the div completely.
[div with overflow](http://jsfiddle.net/dpQ9t/)

```
.c{    
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    background-color:red;
    border-radius:100%;
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:30px;
}
```

Now how to find this using jquery.Thanks

Comment: @Itay I just want to detect the overflow.font-size is not a matter

Comment: " by this i can reduce the font-size so that the text content will fit in the div completely."

Comment: @Itay should i want to edit the question then

Comment: Edit the question to clarify

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? [Use jQuery to Detect Container Overflow?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112106/use-jquery-to-detect-container-overflow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
var c;
var max_height;
var current_height;
var current_font_size;

function fitFontSize(){
    current_height = c.height();
    current_font_size = parseInt( c.css("font-size") );
    if(current_height > max_height){
        console.log("Overflow!")
        current_font_size --;
        c.css("font-size" , current_font_size+"px") ;       
        fitFontSize();
    }
}

$(function(){
    c = $(".c");
    max_height = parseInt( c.css("min-height") );
    fitFontSize();
});
```

The trick is to use `min-height` instead of `height`.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dpQ9t/2/

Comment: Browser not responding.why is this happening

Comment: @rram oops , sorry ! what browser type it is?

Comment: am using firefox and running it in local server

Comment: and also i can't able to see any text not even tiny text when i see from chrome

Comment: only working in your fiddle. any idea on what wrong? @Cherniv

Comment: @rram try this: http://jsfiddle.net/cherniv/dpQ9t/5/ i have added some limitation to prevent infinite looping

Comment: am getting `font-size:0px` @Cherniv

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37011/discussion-between-rram-and-cherniv)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the solution is to think the problem like this:

1. We have a circle of variable radius.
2. We have a square inside the circle with maximum possible side length.
3. We have to make sure the square fits inside the circle by adjusting it's side length.

Obviously, the circle represents your outer div and the square represents the text inside. I wrote some jQuery function to do exactly what you want.

Here is a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hQRrX/). Hope it helps.

Now to explain this,

- First we put all our texts inside an inner div. This is to make sure we can calculate the height and width properly.

  ```
  <div class="circle">
      <div class="text">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta, quisquam, mollitia, dolores sit accusamus molestiae necessitatibus rerum nisi natus itaque amet maiores tempore veniam qui aut ullam odio magnam quidem!
      </div>
  </div>
  ```
- We also make sure the text box padding doesn't get into way by setting the `box-sizing`

  ```
  .circle .text {
      border: 1px solid #bbb;
      background: #fff;
      font-size: 16px;
      /* This box sizing is necessary for inner calculations */
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      padding: 5px;
  }
  ```
- Finally we put our javascript to compute the font size property if the text div height is greater than the calculated square side length. Otherwise, we just adjust the margin to make it appear in a central position.

  ```
  $('.circle').each(function() {
      //Get the container and inner text
      var circle = $(this),
      text = $(this).find('>.text');


      //Get some variables
      var height = circle.height(),
      width = circle.width(),
      radius = 0,
      sideLength = 0,
      margin = 0,
      fontSize = 0;

      //Fix it if necessary
      if(height !== width) {
          radius = Math.round(parseFloat(Math.max(height, width) / 2, 10));
          circle.height(radius * 2).width(radius * 2);
      } else {
          radius = Math.round(height / 2);
      }

      //Now calculate a square box inside the circle to put the text into
      //This is pure maths
      //The diagonal of the square is basically two times of the radius
      //Which means side is approximately radius * 1.4142
      sideLength = Math.round(radius * 1.4142);

      //Thus calculate the margin
      margin = ( height - sideLength ) / 2;

      //Assign the width
      text.css('width', sideLength);

      //Assign the margin
      text.css({
          'margin-left' : margin,
          'margin-top' : margin
      });

      //lets center the text if it's height is less than sideLenght
      if(text.height() < sideLength) {
          var newMarginTop = (height - text.height()) / 2;
          text.css('margin-top', newMarginTop);
      } else if(text.height() > sideLength) { //Or adjust the font
          //Now keep on decreasing the font until the height of the text becomes
          //less than or equal to the calculated size
          while(text.height() > sideLength) {
              fontSize = parseInt(text.css('font-size'), 10);
              text.css('font-size', --fontSize);
          }
      }
  });
  ```

Hope I'm able to explain. Let me know if you do not understand anything.

Comment: @rram Kind of strange. Can you show me if you did any modifications to the code? Also, make sure to use the similar markup. You need to put it like this `<div class="circle"><div class="text">Your Text</div></div>`.