# Find where the text is cut in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to know (in javascript or jQuery) where the text is cut in a div that have a overflow=hidden CSS property ?

I would like to have my text in two differents div the begining in the first and the end in the second one.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112106/use-jquery-to-detect-container-overflow

Comment: That is just for knowing if there is a overflow or not.

Answer (score 2):

what you need is **CSS Regions** http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-regions/

**CSS Regions** is a method of flowing content into multiple elements.

It is a w3c working draft not fully implemented yet in all the browsers.

It's currently supported in Safari and, partially, in IE. There are no plans to implement it in Firefox or Chrome, yet.

Comment: ok, thanks. But it have to works with firefox, chrome, safari and IE 10+