# Creating a Firefox Tab overflow effect

Tags: jquery, scroll, scrollbar, overflow

I would like to create the same overflow effect as you can see in Firefox tabs. When the tabs reach the right side where you can see an overflow arrow, the arrow highlights to let you scroll.

Can this functionality be achieved on a web page using jQuery?

Any hints or solutions welcome.

Comment: check this and see if helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059743/detect-elements-overflow-using-jquery , maybe detecting the overflow, you can work with something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a plugin that uses the jQuery UI tabs and converts them into a horizontal scrollable tab list:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/scrollabletabs

Demo at: http://jquery.aamirafridi.com/jst/#examples