# Truncate/increase font size within a div so it fits

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Suppose I have a `div` of size `100px x 20px` and text within it set randomly with different lengths i.e. some text sections are long and some are short.

So, when the amount of text is less, then there is blank space within the div. And if there is large amount of text, it overflows.

#### My objectives

- If text is less than the `div` capacity, then the `font-size` of that text will maximize to fit within that `div` as much as possible without ***clipping/ cutting***.
- But if text size is larger than the `div` capacity then I want to ***truncate*** text and append `...` (3 dots only).

Comment: I think [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059743/detect-elements-overflow-using-jquery) is a bit similar, and can give you a start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the first part, I'd suggest to wrap the text in a `<span>` so you can get its `offsetWidth`, then you can set its `font-size` style property to `200 / span.offsetWidth`.
Keep in mind, though, that this is a rough calculations with some approximations being made, and maybe you want to do better using 190 or 195 instead of 200.

For the second part, just set `overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;`.
Keep in mind that the ellipsis dots don't appear in older Firefox clients.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need another (inner) `<div>` in order to be able to check the height of the text.

```
<div id="mainDiv">
    <div class="inner">
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
</div>

//css
#mainDiv
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Then you will need some simple functions (something like this):

```
//pseudocode

function doCheck()
{
    if (".inner".height > "#mainDiv".height) truncate()
    else increaseSize()
}

function truncate()
{
    for (i = 1; i <= ".inner".wordCount)
    while (".inner".height <= "#mainDiv".height)
    {
        addOneMoreWord() + " …";
        if (".inner".height > "#mainDiv".height) removeLastWord()
    }
}
//similar thing for increaseSize();
```