# Test if page has a horizontal scrollbar (computer & mobile devices)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cross-browser, scrollbar

On a web page, I need to test if there is a horizontal scrollbar or not (so that I programmatically change the css of some other element).  Is there some way to get that information using jquery (or pure javascript)?

I tested

```
function isHorizontalScrollbarEnabled() {
    return $(document).width()!=$(window).width();
}
```

but it does not seem to work with all browsers (does not work for example with a recent Samsung phone I tested).  I need it to work with all browsers, including recent mobile devices.

Thank you!

**EDIT 1**

I tested the solutions provided by plalx and laconbass, tested IE8, Firefox, Chrome and iPad.  Works with IE, Firefox & Chrome but not as I want on the iPad.

The problem seems related to the zooming feature on mobile devices: even though, when I zoom in on the iPad, a horizontal scrollbar appears, `document`, `window` and `document.body` widths do not change (was also the same problem with the Samsung phone I tested earlier today).

Here is the code I used to test:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <title>test</title>
    </head>

    <body>
      <div style="width: 500px; background: red;" id="test">click here to test</div>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        var i = 1;
        $("#test").click(function(){
          $(this).html("Test #" + (i++) 
    + "<br>document width=" + $(document).width() + ", windows width=" + $(window).width()
    + "<br>document width=" + $(document).width() + ", body width=" + $(document.body).width()
          );  
        });     
      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any idea how to detect the presence of a horizontal scrollbar that also works after zooming in/out on a mobile device like iPad?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059743/detect-elements-overflow-using-jquery

Comment: I tried the solution suggested on that post, works with chrome but with firefox, `$("body")[0].scrollWidth` and `$("body")[0].clientWidth` are equal even if there is an horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: @plalx Maybe the question is the same but IMO it's a lot more clear this one

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Answer (score 7):

```
//scrol 1px to the left
$(document).scrollLeft(1);

if($(document).scrollLeft() != 0){
   //there's a scroll bar
}else{
   //there's no scrollbar
}

//scroll back to original location
$(document).scrollLeft(0);
```

This works because JQuery won't be able to scroll the screen if no scrollbar is available

Comment: functional but not elegant, IMO

Comment: I like it because it's detecting object functionality instead of using math to theoretically determine if there is a scrollbar.  I think it's more elegant, actually.

Comment: @mrbinky3000 I agree on the fact that it's more correct detecting the functionality instead of theoretically calculations. I don't agree it's more elegant, elegance is not only the feature. Refactoring would change my opinion for sure ;)

Comment: This solution works while `elem.get(0).scrollWidth > elem.width()` is failing for me in Chrome. +1

Comment: Not working for this site http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/practical-css-parallax/horizontal-scroll/ for instance.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT 2**: I got a downvote because this doesn't work for nothing but the page so I built a generic solution based on @Pabs123's answer, only for fun:

```js
function hasScrollX( selector ){
    var e = $(selector), fn = 'scrollLeft';
    return e[fn](1) && e[fn]() > 0 && e[fn](0) && true;
}
```

or even

```js
jQuery.fn.hasScrollX = function( ){
    var fn = 'scrollLeft';
    return this[fn](1) && this[fn]() > 0 && this[fn](0) && true;
}
```

See it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BwSVM/4/), and how it can be easily adapted to detect vertical scrollbar presence.

**EDIT**: Tested & working on chrome and firefox. As jQuery team does the crossbrowsing work, **i suggest the use of jQuery rather than native javascript**.

I were curious about how to do this in an elegant way than the suggested previously (which actually work)

The following comparison work to me

```js
$(document).width() > $(window).width()
```

you can see it in action [with scroll bar](http://jsfiddle.net/BwSVM/) and [without it](http://jsfiddle.net/xyCph/)

Comment: I see lots of answers implementing this solution, but it is not working reliably for me on a text area.

Comment: @tponthieux The scroll feature detection posted by pabs123 should work for your case, check it